# Why gcc function attribute noplt makes my program slower?

Tags: linux, matplotlib

I have a test shared library, which includes one function :

```
int func(){return 1;}
```

And my main program is

```
#ifdef NOPLT 
#define _NOPLT __attribute__ ((noplt))
#else
#define _NOPLT
#endif

extern int func() _NOPLT;

int fun1(){
    unsigned int i=0;
    long j = 0;
    while(++i) j+= func();
    return j;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return fun1();
}
```

I compile it as below:

```
pqy@pqy-E400:~/Desktop$ gcc t.c -fPIC -shared -o libt.so
pqy@pqy-E400:~/Desktop$ gcc m.c -g -o m_noplt -DNOPLT -L. -lt -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
pqy@pqy-E400:~/Desktop$ gcc m.c -g -o m_plt -L. -lt -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
```

Then measure the running time of each program:

```
pqy@pqy-E400:~/Desktop$ time ./m_noplt;time ./m_noplt;time ./m_noplt

real    0m10.758s
user    0m10.758s
sys     0m0.000s

real    0m10.689s
user    0m10.689s
sys     0m0.000s

real    0m10.683s
user    0m10.683s
sys     0m0.000s
pqy@pqy-E400:~/Desktop$ time ./m_plt;time ./m_plt;time ./m_plt

real    0m10.041s
user    0m10.036s
sys     0m0.000s

real    0m9.958s
user    0m9.957s
sys     0m0.000s

real    0m9.970s
user    0m9.957s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Looks like noplt is 5% slower than plt. Gcc manual says:
*The noplt attribute on function foo tells the compiler to assume that the function foo is externally defined and that the call to foo must avoid the PLT in position-independent code.
In position-dependent code, a few targets also convert calls to functions that are marked to not use the PLT to use the GOT instead.*

Sounds like noplt should be faster since it skips PLT. Have I mistaken it?

Comment: I think you should do three things. First, you should also move the processor from a low-power state to a performance state before testing. Maybe a script like [`governor.sh`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/TestScripts/governor.sh). Second, I believe the PLT functions are lazy-bound. You should probably include `-Wl,-z,now`. Also see the [`ld(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld). Finally, start measuring time when `main` gets control.

Comment: Oh. I really don;t know why. This behaviour happens when I use i7-4700mq in a laptop. When I switch to a desktop cpu i5-3470, noplt is 10% faster!